# Typed configuration data in a separate config file in ASP.Net 4.0?

Tags: asp.net, configuration, .net-4.0, web-config, enterprise-library

1. I have an asp.net 4.0 web application.
2. I need extensive configuration data for this web application, that is strongly typed and the structure of this configuration data is going to be fairly complex (cannot do with key-value pairs). In the past I remember having done this in .Net 2.0 but cannot figure out how I will do it in .Net 4.0. The class and config mapping is like shown below (really simplified for the purpose of illustration only):

   ```
    class SettingsClass
    {
     int count;
     string name;
     decimal amount;
    }

    <SettingsClass>
     <count>2</count>
     <name>Moiz</name>
     <decimal>10.66</decimal>
    </SettingsClass>
   ```

   1. I need this configuration in a separate file (other than the web.config).
   2. I don't think I would have to write explicit serialization/deserialization code.

Does .Net 4.0 configuration classes provide this kind of built in facility?

Would I need to use Enterprise Library 5.0 to get this done?

Answer (score 1):

You can introduce strongly typed sections in configuration files with [custom configuration handlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx).

If you need these configurations in a separate file you can use [OpenMappedExeConfiguration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en/us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.openmappedexeconfiguration.aspx) to load additional configuration files.

You can use both practices in .NET 2.0 and 4.0.

Comment: You can also use the configSource attribute to point to the location of your config file for that section: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.sectioninformation.configsource.aspx